# The if-statement is triggered no matter the input

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, input

I'm trying to code some kind of multiple-choice kinda game, but no matter the input, the if-statement is always triggered, even if the input is d or D.

It might be an obvious mistake, but I'm an absolute beginner at programming, so I really hope you guys can help me point out what I've done wrong.

My code looks like this:

```
answer = input("Do you want to do something (C) or something else (D)? [C/D]")

if answer == "c" or "C":
    print ("You typed", answer)
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("You can now do something")
    time.sleep(2)


elif answer == "d" or "D":
    print ("You typed", answer)
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("You can now do something else")
    time.sleep(2)


else:
    Exit()
```

Comment: use `if answer.lower() == "c":`, `elif answer.lower() == "d":`

Comment: If you want it shorter: `if answer in ['c','C']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python works different from the english language.

`if answer == "c" or "C":` should be `if answer == "c" or answer == "C":`
Similarly for `D`.

This question has been previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true). You can read more about logical OR [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction).

Answer (score 1):

```
answer = input("Do you want to do something (C) or something else (D)? [C/D]")

if answer == "c" or answer == "C": # Here is your mistake
    print ("You typed", answer)
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("You can now do something")
    time.sleep(2)


elif answer == "d" or answer == "D":  # also here
    print ("You typed", answer)
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("You can now do something else")
    time.sleep(2)


else:
    Exit()
```